# How can I detect wrong data types?

Tags: c++, types

I have this program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int calculateResultAndPrintIt(int firstNr, char operand, int secondNr)
{
    int sum = 0;
    if(operand == '+')
        sum = firstNr + secondNr;

    else if(operand == '-')
        sum = firstNr - secondNr;

    else if(operand == '*')
        sum = firstNr * secondNr;

    else if(operand == '/')
        sum = firstNr / secondNr;

    else
    {
        cout << "Invalid operation! Returning!";
        return -1;
    }

    cout << firstNr << " " << operand << " " << secondNr << " is " << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    int firstNr = 0;
    char operand = '+';
    int secondNr = 0;

    cout << "Enter a value: ";
    cin >> firstNr;

    cout << "Enter a second value: ";
    cin >> secondNr;

    cout << "Enter one of the following: +, -, *, or /: ";
    cin >> operand;

    int back = calculateResultAndPrintIt(firstNr, operand, secondNr);

    if(back != 0)
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

When it asks me "Enter a value: " or "Enter a second value: " and I enter something like 'l' then it shows like that:

Enter a number: l
Enter a second value: Enter one of the following: +, -, *, or /: 0 + 0 is 0

But what I want is that I can show message "Not a integer!" when user types in a character!
Like:

Enter a number: l
Not a integer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After calling `cin`, check:

```
if (!cin)
{
    cout << "Not an integer!" << endl;
}
```

Alternatively, `cin` sets something called a failbit when the input is mismatched.  You can test this with `cin.fail()`

Comment: Thanks, this worked now it shows that message EDIT: both of them work